# How to delete all files from hdfs directory with scala

Tags: scala, hadoop, hdfs

For a project I am currently working on with Scala and Spark, I have to make a code that checks if the hdfs directory I am working on is empty, and if it is not, I have to remove every files from the directory.

Before I deploy my code into Azur, I am testing it with a local directory from my computer.

I am starting with: making a method to delete every files from this directory. This is what I have for now :

```
object DirectoryCleaner {


  val spark:SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local[3]")
    .appName("SparkByExamples.com")
    .getOrCreate()

  val fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration)
  val srcPath=new Path("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\test_dir\\file1.csv")

  def deleFilesDir(): Unit = {
    if(fs.exists(srcPath) && fs.isFile(srcPath))
      fs.delete(srcPath, true)
  }


}
```

With this code, I am able to delete a single file (`file1.csv`). I would like to be able to define my path this way `val srcPath=new Path("C:\\Users\\myuser\\Desktop\\test_dir")` (without specifying any filename), and just delete every files from the `test_dir` directory. Any idea on how I could do that ?

Thank's for helping

Comment: You dont need a SparkContext (or any Spark libraries) to get the FileSystem object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `fs.listFiles` to get all the files in a directory and then loop through them while deleting them. Also, set the `recursive` flag to `false`, so you don't recurse into directories.

```scala
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.{FileSystem, Path}

def deleteAllFiles(directoryPath: String, fs: FileSystem): Unit = {

  val path = new Path(directoryPath)

  // get all files in directory
  val files = fs.listFiles(path, false)

  // print and delete all files
  while (files.hasNext) {
    val file = files.next()
    fs.delete(file.getPath, false)
  }

}

// Example for local, non HDFS path 
val directoryPath = "file:///Users/m_vemuri/project"
val fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration())
deleteAllFiles(directoryPath, fs)
```